# Is it possible to force everyone to comment their code using PhpStorm settings or phpcs?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcs

We're a team of 4 people ready to start working on a project and I want to know if is there a way to force everyone to comment every function, class or big chunk of code that they write before pushing into the repository.

I was thinking if I can make PhpStorm show an error when a function or a class does not have a PHPDoc block that shows in detail what that function/class does.

Comment: Use CodeSniffer or built-in inspections, MD  or other tools

Comment: PhpStorm has [CodeSniffer integration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Quality+Tools). If Code Sniffer itself can report different issues with different severity (error/warning) then PhpStorm *should* also display them similarly (at very least in theory ... because AFAIK it will use "Warning" by default for stuff that comes from external linters). Plus, try configuring standard PhpStorm Inspections (or those provided by "Php Inspections (EA Extended)" plugin) -- 1) not all of them are enabled by default or some options are relaxed 2) increase severity of needed.